# How get products name magento 2 sql database

Tags: product, database, magento2.2, sql

I am trying to get products name(value) and when i see my db table catalog_product_entity_varchar but in which in the column of value all base images are given so please tell accurate table or any method to get products name or value
[image]

Comment: do you want to get the product details by Id???

Comment: are you trying to get it directly in the database, I mean using phpmyadmin etc?

Comment: no i just need products name that save in db with value named

Comment: you need the table that stores the product name?

Comment: yes @magefms i have already explore table like catalog_product_entity_varchar

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses an EAV table structure for products. Names are stored in catalog_product_entity_varchar. If you have the product ID X, you can query this table directly:

```
SELECT entity_id, value, store_id FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
  WHERE entity_id = X AND attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE entity_type_id=4 AND attribute_code='name'
  )
```

The subquery determines the attribute id for "name", entity_type_id 4 is always the type ID for products.

Comment: i have found base images path except value in catalog_product_entity_varchar

Comment: try checking in `catalog_product_entity_text`

Comment: NO its not required value or exact product name